# How do you serve php files located outside of the apache folders

Tags: apache-2.2, php, mod-php

I've just installed `phpMyAdmin` at `/usr/share/phpMyAdmin` on a CentOS 5 machine running `webmin` / `virtualmin`. I have also added an alias to the apache config, being the following line:

```
Alias /phpMyAdmin /usr/share/phpMyAdmin
```

So that when I visit `www.foobar.com/phpMyAdmin` it serves `phpMyAdmin`. The problem is that the php is not being parsed, and is instead being spat out with the html which greatly diminishes the usefullness of what I have done. How can I set up apache or php or whatever to parse phpMyAdmin correctly.

When googling this I wasn't able to get an understandable answer, however the most common related question was whether I am running `mod_php` or as CGI. php is running via CGI

Thanks

Comment: is php working as it should be otherwise in that foobar.com domain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lobe, it sounds like you need the line:

AddType application/x-httpd-php .php

added to your apache configuration.

Comment: This breaks mod_fcgid/suexec in VirtualHost sections. It's better to do this specifically for the directory you want this to work on; or to do it for specific VirtualHosts where you want phpmyadmin to run from the server-wide installation. A safer option may be to install phpmyadmin inside a virtual host, rather than using the apt-provided package, so that it can run under suexec and as a normal user (the Debian/Ubuntu package runs as the Apache user).